# Organizing Boxes Into Shape of Letter with Inkscape?

Tags: inkscape

Suppose we have 100 small square shape paths.  We want to turn these into the shape of the letter E.  Is there a plugin or extension or technique in Inkscape that allows us to do this?

I'm thinking approximately create a 100 small somewhat randomized boxes using the clone tool and then mask a letter of them....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using the spray tool for this?

It has options to

- randomize
- spray clones
- prevent overlaps, with distance setting
- only spray on areas that are not transparent (i.e. on existing letters on an empty background)

Comment: I made a letter and I'm attempting to spray the inside of the letter, but the boxes are being sprayed pretty much anywhere I point the mouse.  Is there a way to spray them only inside the letter?

Comment: Yes, disable the setting for spraying on transparency (hover text: Apply over transparent areas, icon: eye), and put the letter on an empty background (as written above).

Answer (score 1):

Are the boxes of equal size, color, stroke width and orientation? So for example you would represent the upper, horizontal line of the E with 7 boxes in width, 3 in height, each with equal spacing?

You might either do it by cloning 2, 3 sample squares, positioning them and then look at the XML and generate all the square clones with a short script.

Or, if the background is for instance white, spread your squares which needn't be in such a strict order and hide some of them below 2 big white squares or pick the squares to delete with drawing the mouse over the black (colored) squares to be removed.

[image]

For the first E, I made 7 clones, aligned them at top with the align tool, then equal spacing, then grouped the seven and made 9 copies of the group, aligned the groups left, equal vertical spacing, then broke 4 of the groups and removed the 5 superflous squares of these lines 3, 4, 7 and 8.

For the second version, I made a clone, used the spray tool to distribute the squares on the field. Used the align tool again, since I use the german version I describe the location of the tool: The 3rd group, ordering or placement, the 2 most right options, random distribution and unclump.

Then I made 2 squares, which roughly fit into the space at the E at the left, moved them to the right, and selected a space a little wider and deleted all the so marked objects.